# jquery popup - Model Opens another pop -up Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax

Spec :  jquery-3.1.0_min.js

I have a jQuery Modal pop-up with a for-loop, along with content fed into by an Ajax request.

I need 1st modal pop-up on-click through the for-loop to open up a 2nd modal popup, and also send some data sent to the 2nd modal as pop-up.

1st Modal

```
modelDetail_Wbs_base = function(httpServ){
  $('.openeval_WSC').click(function () {
    $("#wbs_srvr_dialog1").dialog({
      $.each(val,function(k,v){
        if((urlTmp != "--") && (env == 'DAO')){
          wsdta = wsdta +"<div id='mopenevala_WDTA' Service='DATA-SERVICE'       
          hst="+urlTmp+" ><li><a href='#'>"+urlTmp+"</a></li></div>";
        }
      }
    }); 
  });
}
```

2nd Modal

```
modelDetail_Wbs_dtls = function(httpServ){      
  $('#mopenevala_WDTA').click(function(){       
    alert("!!! HELL");
  });           
}
```

Question : I am not able to open the 2nd modal. Any suggestion?

Comment: you seem to have a syntax error in your first snippet - .each is not closed properly

Comment: Sir that was just a snippet limited code inserted in the form... the actual code has the brackets '}' properly closed ......

Comment: ok but how can we fix your code if it's not the real version and also has errors in it? We don't know which are real problems and which are just because it's a smaller snippet.

Comment: But if your real code compiles, and the modal is not opening, have you checked for any errors etc in your browser console? And as Vijaya's answer says, you also have a potential problem with duplicated IDs, since you generate the markup using a loop. Duplicate IDs are invalid in HTML, they need to be unique (if something's not unique, then logically it cannot be an ID!)

Comment: Accepted that the code sample has duplicate ID's so changing to "class' ... also did not work,  is this also need to be unique ?.

Comment: No, class doesn't need to be unique. Perhaps there's something else at play. Like I said, did you check for console errors etc? Have you checked these functions are actually executed (you can put console logging in or set breakpoints etc to show if it's running)

Comment: I did do debugging using Firebug, with some console logs and the console did not display any error's.

Answer (score 0):

Make the **id** as **class**

In 1st modal :

```
 wsdta = wsdta +"<div class='mopenevala_WDTA' Service='DATA-SERVICE' hst="+urlTmp+" ><li><a href='#'>"+urlTmp+"</a></li></div>";
```

In 2nd Modal :

```
 $('.mopenevala_WDTA').click(function(){
     alert('Hi');
});
```

Comment: Sir I already tried this code sample...suggested in one of the forms...this did- not work